# titanium image factory quality

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, titanium-modules

I have this code that works perfectly on iOS but crashes on android platform.

```
var quality = Ti.Platform.osname=="android"?80:ImageFactory.QUALITY_LOW;
Ti.API.info(quality);
var resizedImage = ImageFactory.imageAsResized(imageView, {height : h,width:w, quality: quality});
```

the 2nd line of code shows 80, but I got an error that says

```
[INFO] :   80
[WARN] :   W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: quality must be 0..100
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:873)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at ti.imagefactory.ImageFactoryModule.imageTransform(ImageFactoryModule.java:137)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at ti.imagefactory.ImageFactoryModule.imageAsResized(ImageFactoryModule.java:181)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Function.nativeInvoke(Native Method)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Function.callSync(V8Function.java:57)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Function.call(V8Function.java:43)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Function$1.run(V8Function.java:70)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:112)
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [454,43722] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,43722] - In views/share.js:58,34
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,43722] - Message: Uncaught Error: quality must be 0..100
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,43722] - Source:
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at views/share.js:58: Uncaught Error: quality must be 0..100
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (Ti.Platform.osname=="android"){
    // For android
    resizedImage = ImageFactory.imageAsResized(imageView, {height : h,width:w});
}else{
    // For iOS
    resizedImage = ImageFactory.imageAsResized(imageView, {height : h,width:w, quality: quality});
}
```

for more please refer app.js of [android](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/blob/master/imagefactory/mobile/android/example/app.js) and [iOS](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/blob/master/imagefactory/mobile/ios/example/app.js)

Comment: of course it works! I want to reduce the quality of the image because of server match requirements, but I guess it's not possible...

now I see that I already ".compress(blob,0.5)" the image blob, so I don't need to set the quality of that image view. still remain the bug, though

Answer (score 0):

For image resizing you can use.

```
[TiBlob] imageAsResized([int] width, [int] height)
```

Example : -

```
var blob = myimage.toBlob();
var smallBlob = blob.imageAsResized(80, 80);
```

also [refer](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/118694/image-resizing-and-more)